# Why can bridged Docker containers access the host-network(s)?

Tags: docker, docker-network

Today, debugging in a legacy docker-compose stack I noticed something that I never noticed before and which feels kind of odd to me:

Having any container connected to a `bridge` or a newly created user defined network using the `bridge` driver, I can not only access ressources also connected to this network (which I expect) but also any IPs from my Host's network (which I didnt think was possible since I thought that containers network is isolated).

Example:

A newly created container, using `bridge` as network (with its IP being something like 172.17.0.3) can also ping my host's router (192.168.178.1), any ressources in the hosts network (192.168.178.X) and even ressources in the host's VPN-connection (10.10.x.x).

Can someone provide an explanation for that behaviour? Maybe it is completely natural and I just didnt notice it yet but up to now I thought that container-networking is completely isolated towards the host (except for explicit port-forwarding and the `host`-Network on Linux-Dockerhosts).

Comment: That's normal.  On a native-Linux non-Docker-Desktop setup, Docker creates a virtual interface for each Docker network (`ifconfig` will show them) and creates iptables NAT rules to allow outbound connections.

Comment: Thanks! Fixing intercontainer communication is a standard problem, but I never thought about it in this direction before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're observing is expected behaviuor in the default configuration of Docker networks:

By default, Docker creates a bridge network (`docker0` bridge), which is a private internal network created by Docker on the host. Containers connected to this bridge network are given an IP address from the private range that Docker maintains (like `172.17.0.2`, `172.17.0.3`, etc.), and this network acts as a standard Ethernet bridge that forwards packets between the network segments it connects.

Containers connected to the default bridge network can communicate with the host machine because Docker configures the host machine's network stack to route traffic to and from the bridge network. The host acts as a gateway for the containers to the outside world.

The Docker daemon on the host machine configures NAT (Network Address Translation) rules to allow containers to access external networks. When a container tries to connect to an external IP, the packets are masqueraded as originating from the host, allowing them to pass out to the external network.

When your host is connected to a VPN, the network interface that the VPN creates on the host machine is also subject to the host's routing and NAT rules. This means that containers on the bridge network can also route traffic through the VPN connection. This is because the VPN's virtual network adapter is present on the host and Docker containers use the host's network stack.

While containers can access external networks, this doesn't mean they're not isolated. Isolation here refers to container-to-container isolation within the same host, which is controlled by Docker network policies. Also, without port mapping, services within a container are not accessible from external networks unless explicitly configured.

When you create a user-defined bridge network, it behaves similarly to the default bridge network, but with some additional features like better isolation and custom network plugins.

You can find more details in following links:

[Bridge network driver](https://docs.docker.com/network/drivers/bridge/)

[Making a Docker Container Use a VPN](https://www.naturalborncoder.com/linux/2021/02/19/making-a-docker-container-use-a-vpn/)

Comment: Thanks for the extensive answer! I spent a lot of time searching for the exact reason for that behavior and started thinking I missconfigured something.